# Visual Studio 2019 white window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I installed Visual Studio 2019 recently. When I run it it also opens "white window" and it cannot be closed. Any ideas how to close it or hide it?[image] [image: White window]

It is quite annoying and I dont know how to fix it..

Comment: Maybe it's some extension or plug-in for Visual Studio. Disable all extensions to see if the window goes away.

Comment: @Dialecticus Yeah, it is cause by one extention which I need for the project...

Comment: The makers of the extension are the only ones who can help you now.